# Thread.Interrupt() Not working as intended in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

### Here is my Code:

Calling interrupt does stop thread, but just for a split second, immediately, the thread continues, but why? **My current solution to this problem is to use ArrayList to manage threads**, and loop over the ArrayList to stop the threads. Though this works, but certainly is not good. Can anyone help me with that?

---

```
private Thread thread;
private static final String TAG = "StoragePresenter";

public void refreshVolumes(boolean isRunning) {
    if (isRunning) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while " + thread.isInterrupted());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(refreshDelay);
                    Log.d(TAG, "refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); //Thread -> 9
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                handler.post(this::getVolumes);
            }
        };
        thread = new Thread(runnable);
        Log.d(TAG, "refreshVolumes: start thread's name -> " + thread.getName());
        thread.start(); // Thread -> 9 started
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "refreshVolumes: interrupt thread's name -> " + thread.getName());
        thread.interrupt(); // Thread -> 9 interrupted
        Log.d(TAG, "refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? " + thread.isInterrupted());
        Log.d(TAG, "refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? 2x " + thread.isInterrupted());
    }
}
```

---

Logcat output:

```
        ////////////////////////////////////
        called refreshVolumes(true)
        ////////////////////////////////////
        08-09 17:41:29.687 924-1811/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev/com.xxxxxxxxx.app.ui.main.settings.storage.StorageActivity} from uid 10293
        08-09 17:41:29.767 26451-26451/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: start thread's name -> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:29.768 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:41:29.927 924-995/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev/com.xxxxxxxxx.app.ui.main.settings.storage.StorageActivity: +210ms
        08-09 17:41:33.269 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:33.271 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:41:36.772 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:36.773 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:41:40.274 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:40.275 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:41:43.776 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:43.777 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:41:47.278 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:47.279 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:47.280 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:41:50.780 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        ////////////////////////////////////
        called refreshVolumes(false)
        ////////////////////////////////////
        08-09 17:41:50.861 26451-26451/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev
D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: interrupt thread's name -> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:50.862 26451-26451/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? true
            refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? 2x false
        08-09 17:41:50.862 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:41:54.362 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:54.363 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:54.376 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:41:57.878 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:41:57.879 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:42:01.380 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:42:01.381 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:42:04.882 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:42:04.883 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:42:08.384 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
        08-09 17:42:08.385 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in runnable WHILE ---> Thread-9
            refreshVolumes: thread.isInterrupted? above while false
        08-09 17:42:11.886 26451-26676/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.dev D/StoragePresenter: refreshVolumes: in TRY ---> Thread-9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [`Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) throws `InterruptedException` (due to being interrupted while sleeping), it clears the interrupt flag. You should actually handle the `InterruptedException` and use the `catch` block to break out of the loop if you want it to work this way.

Comment: I have tried that, however, it is still not working. But I got it working by setting the ```thread == null``` and then use the null pointer exception to break the loop.

Comment: @Haomin omg, no; just don't ignore the `InterruptedException`. Put `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` in the catch block, and this problem is solved, as @VeeArr suggests.

Comment: @bowmore I used catch InterruptedException first of course, since the thread is sleeping, it should generate an InterruptedException. However, the catch block was never reached. That is why I change it to ignored. In the meantime, I am sure that I am operating on the same thread.

Comment: regardless, you must handle the InterruptedException.

Comment: @bowmore __Sorry my mistake__, it is __catched__, and this time I called thread.interrupt (thread is the name of the Thread), it worked. Thank you both.